# Creating route (by hand) over a road shape in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, interpolation, route, trace

Is it possible to create a route placing some waypoints by hand? I mean, I don't want the program (QGIS) to link consecutive points with a simple line. I want it to link the points following the road shape of a city layer, so that with a few clicks I can recreate a large path. Any idea of how to do it?

And, once the entire route is generated, is it possible to interpolate its waypoints? And what would be the format of the new file?

Comment: if you have vector roads data then the trace tool in advanced feature editing should work for you

Comment: Thank you very much iant, I have a vector layer of my city's roads (polylines) but I don't find the trace tool that you mention. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Trace is new in QGIS 2.14 see the changelog: http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog214/#feature-trace-digitising-tool It has links to guides.

Comment: Okay! I will try updating my program. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

If you have vector roads data then the new (>2.14) trace tool in advanced feature editing should work for you.